# Missing argument for parameter 'item' in call

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm creating a news app with Swift UI and I use firebase. But I always have the same error : "Missing argument for parameter 'item' in call". I use firebase Firestore, to stock my article Data, here it's called "item". I when I use "(item.[...] ?? "") to input my text I have the problem. I don't know why.

```
// This is my code where I don't have a problem

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Ballcap

struct SwiftUIView: View {

    @ObjectBinding var dataSource: ItemDatabase = ItemDatabase()

    var item: Item

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text(item.categorie ?? "")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.green)

            List {
                ForEach(self.dataSource.items.identified(by: \.id)) { item in
                    MediumArticleItem(item: item.data!)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct MediumArticleItem : View {

        var item: Item

        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Image("test")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .shadow(radius: 3)

                Spacer()

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5.0) {
                    Text(item.title ?? "")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        Text(item.body ?? "")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .lineLimit(4)

                        }
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                Spacer()

                    }
            .frame(width: 330)
        }
    }
}

// This is the end of my  View File and where I have a problem: 

#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        if FirebaseApp.app() != nil {
                    FirebaseApp.configure()
                }
        return SwiftUIView() 
  // the problem is here...
    }
}
#endif

// ...and it proposed me to fix it buy this : 

#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        if FirebaseApp.app() != nil {
                    FirebaseApp.configure()
                }
        return SwiftUIView(item: Item)  // <- but now I have a new error and it's wrote : "Cannot convert value // of type 'Item.Type' to expected argument type 'Item' "

    }
}
#endif


// I have two models files for the connection to Firestore : 
// This one is my Item.swift

import SwiftUI
import Ballcap
import Firebase


struct Item: Modelable, Codable, Hashable {

    var title: String?

    var body: String?

    var body2: String?

    var body3: String?

    var categorie: String?

    var author: String?

}

// And this one is my ItemDataSource file :


import Ballcap
import Firebase
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ItemDatabase: BindableObject {

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var _dataSource: DataSource<Document<Item>>?

    var items: [Document<Item>] = [] {
        willSet { self.willChange.send() }
    }

    init() {
        _dataSource = DataSource<Document<Item>>.Query(Document<Item>.collectionReference).dataSource()
            .onCompleted({ [weak self] (_, items) in
                self?.items = items
            }).listen()
    }
}
```

I would like to have no more error and I would like to know why I have this error.

Comment: I think there's a pretty good answer but can you clarify what you're trying to do with this line of code `return SwiftUIView(item: Item)`? What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `SwiftUIView` has a property defined as:

```swift
var item: Item
```

This means that unless you create an initializer for your view, the compiler will synthesize one for you. In this case, something close to this:

```swift
init(dataSource: ItemDatabase = ItemDatabase(), item: Item) {
  self.dataSource = dataSource
  self.item = item
}
```

This is why you are forced to create your view, passing an item as parameter.

As for the error in:

```swift
SwiftUIView(item: Item) // dataSource can be omitted, because the initilizer has a default value
```

`Item` is not a value, it is a type. Imagine that you had a function that requires an integer, and instead of doing this: `myfunc(value: 3)`, you do this: `myfunc(value: Int)`. This is what the compiler is telling you, but the type is `Item`, instead of `Int`.

So you need to create a value of type Item, using its initializer:

```swift
SwiftUIView(item: Item(title: "abc", ....)) // use the right initializer here
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it print the text which I input in that : SwiftUIView(item: Item(title: "abc", ....)). And I don't know how to change it, because I would like it print the category name of my article and I present inside firebase

Comment: @MathieuCloart Not an experienced iOS dev here, but the idea is that the preview, i.e. what the view `SwiftUIView_Previews` presents in the Live View, needs some data to populate `SwiftUIView` with. If you have dynamic data to populate the previewed view with, then you can feed that into the preview via `SwiftUIView(item: Item(title: "\(dynamicData)", ...))`. Otherwise, the preview will contain your static data.